# Python flask - refresh html view when a database change has accrued

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm developing a stock market app with a python flask framework.
The user has a route where he can see his details and the number of shares.

If a change in the user shares has occurred, I would like it to be displayed automatically. (Without the need for the user to refresh the page).

To make a long story short, I would like the '/user_page/<user_name>' route to refresh automatically when the '/update_page/' route is writing to the DB.

```
@app.route('/user_page/<user_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_page(user_name):
    user = Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user_name).first()
    return render_template('user_page.html', user=user)

@app.route('/update_page/<user_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_user_holdiongs(user_name):
    if user_name.bid > last_bid:
        change = TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=user_name.id).update(dict(share_amount=user_name.share_amount - bid.share_amount))

db.session.add(bid)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: You could use AJAX to achieve this. What do you use for your frontend ?

Comment: Just a plain HTML no framework

Comment: You should use Javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to monitor changes on your backend and refresh (or rewrite) page. 
 You need something like that:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // AJAX send request
    $.ajax({
        url: "your url here",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function (request, error) {}
    });
}, 30000);  // check about changes every 30 seconds
```

Comment: @Monty_emma have a nice day) You can mark answer as correct)